# Other devices with Gmail on

Tags: gmail

If I log out of my Gmail account on my tablet, will this log me out on my computer, or other devices at the same time?

Note: I do not want to do this, because I want to stay logged in on PC.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won’t, unless you specifically do this.

> ### Forgot to sign out?
>
> If you've forgotten to sign out of Gmail on another computer, you can sign out of your other sessions by going to the bottom right corner of Gmail, clicking **Details**, and then **Sign out all other sessions**.

[Source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154).

Also, note that when you sign out from your tablet (or phone for that matter), you sign out of all Google apps you might have on your device for that account.

[Source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3114694).